# Sending Actor Runtime ETW logs to ElasticSearch

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Currently I'm trying out ElasticSearch as a logging solution to pump out ETW events to.

I've followed this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostic-how-to-use-elasticsearch), and this is working great for my own custom ActorEventSource logs, but I haven't found a way to log the Actor Runtime events (ActorMethodStart, ActorMethodStop... etc) using the "in-process" trace capturing.

1) Is this possible using the in-process trace capturing?

I'm also considering using the "out-of-process" trace capturing, which to me seems like the preferable way of doing things in our situation, as we already have WAD setup which includes all of the Actor Runtime events already. Not to mention the potential performance impact / other side-effects of running the ElasticSearchListener inside of our Actor Services.

2) I'm not quite sure how to implement this.The https://github.com/Azure/azure-diagnostics-tools/tree/master/ES-MultiNode project doesn't seem to include Logstash, so i'm assuming I would need a template such as this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-diagnostics-tools/tree/master/ELK-Semantic-Logging/ELK/AzureRM/elk-simple-on-ubuntu, otherwise I would need to modify the ES-MultiNode project to install Logstash as well? Just trying to get an idea if I'm going down the right path with regards to this.

If there's any other suggestions in terms of logging, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Have you given the Service Fabric Analytics OMS solution a look? You can point it to your storage accounts and it can suck in Service Fabric specific events.

Comment: You'll just need to ensure that diagnostics is enabled when you create your cluster.

Comment: I've taken a brief look at Log Analytics. The main stumbling block I ran into was that our ETW application logs are being written to multiple different tables, not just a single "WADETWEventTable". 
The table for upload is the same as (ETWEventTable). I had a bit of difficulty reading the pricing for Log Analytics, but based on my understanding it's
$2.7 per GB of data analyzed with no additional fees per node, as in I don't need to subscribe to any other OMS services to use Log Analytics?

Comment: As per this comment in the documentation "At the moment, OMS can only read application ETW events from that table. However, support for custom ETW tables is in development."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-service-fabric

Comment: I don't believe the Service Fabric Analytics OMS solution was available as of that writing. Also, I think you can do some custom things, but that might fall under "features in preview" that you have to enable.

Comment: By available I mean through the OMS portal.